# TYPO3 xClass and Dependency Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, typo3, hook, extbase

I want to override an Extbase Controller, e.g. news in TYPO3 v10.4. Therefore I register an XClass in my ext_locaconf.php

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects'][\GeorgRinger\News\Controller\NewsController::class] = [
    'className' => \Clickstorm\CsEvents\Controller\EventController::class
];
```

Afterwards I want to inject my new Repository

```
/**
 * eventDateRepository
 * 
 * @var EventDateRepository
 */
protected $eventDateRepository = null;

/**
 * Inject a eventDateRepository
 *
 * @param EventDateRepository $eventDateRepository
 */
public function injectEventDateRepository(EventDateRepository $eventDateRepository)
{
    $this->eventDateRepository = $eventDateRepository;
}
```

But my eventDateRepository is null. Also when I use a constructor instead.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I don't know the reason for such a behaviour, a sustainable workaround is to manually instantiate your dependencies in the `initializeAction` method.

In my case, this is what I wrote:

```php
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Service\ImageService
 */
protected $imageService;

public function initializeAction()
{
    parent::initializeAction();
    $objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
    $this->imageService = $objectManager->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Service\ImageService::class);
}
```